# How can I make a RecyclerView with 2 columns with the contents attached to the sides of the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-gridlayout, item-decoration

I want to implement a `RecyclerView` using a `GridLayoutManager` with 2 columns which will contain `Checkbox`es. I want all the items of the first column to be 'attached' to the left side of the RecyclerView and the items of the right column to be attached on the right side of the RecyclerView.

Here is a diagram of the expected and the actual results:
[image: Differences in implementation]

I have implemented an `ItemDecoration` with adds a fixed value spacing on the right if the item is in the left column and on the left if the item is in the right column, but this does not work for every possible content of the cells because sometimes the fixed value of the spacing does not result in the expected result and needs to be dynamic.

This is the ItemDecoration:

```
class StationListItemDecoration(val spacing: Int) : ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {

        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        val column = position % 2

        if (column == 0) {
            // Left column item, adjust to the start
            outRect.left = 0
            outRect.right = spacing
        } else {
            // Right column item, adjust to the end
            outRect.left = spacing
            outRect.right = 0
        }
    }
}
```

This is the layout of the content of each item in the `RecyclerView`.

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="1245 (4)"/>
```

I do not know what else to try, so any help would be grateful.
Thanks !

Comment: how about aligning text in your text view according to position? If the position is even then align text into left and if the position is odd then align text into right.

Comment: @AhsanUllahRasel You are correct. I wrapped the textView inside a ConstraintLayout and update the child constraints dynamically in the adapter depending on the current position. 
Thanks for the idea !